# getting text from command-line into Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to parse some text that is generated by a command-line command. The command-line command I want to use is Ubuntu's `landscape-sysinfo`. In an attempt to run this, I'm using the following Java code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(new String[] { "landscape-sysinfo" });
```

The thing I'm not sure of is, how do I get the output of the command-line command into a string that I work with in my Java app?

Thank you so much for your valuable insights!

Comment: If you take the time to look at the javadoc for `java.lang.Process`, you will see a `getOutputStream()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hope this one helps its what the  Apprentice Queue said

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class BatchExecuteService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BatchExecuteService batchExecuteService = new BatchExecuteService();
        batchExecuteService.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String cmds[] = {"D:\\test.bat"};
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec(cmds);
            process.getOutputStream().close();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            String strLine = "";
            while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/process_getoutputstream.htm)

[image: Output]